# ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint. Tried many times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem setting up the foriegn key for my table here is the pic

I have tried changing the data type and constarints of the column in the parent table but nothing helped

This is the faculty table:-

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Fid        | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| F_name     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Department | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Subject    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Subject_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is the child table i want to creat:-

```
create table module(Subject_id int(11), 
                    Subject varchar(20), 
                    module_1 blob, 
                    module_2 blob, 
                    module_3 blob, 
                    module_4 blob, 
                    module_5 blob, 
                    foreign key (Subject_id) references faculty(Subject_id));
```

I get this error:-

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Are both the tables InnoDB ? Note that Foreign Key constraints don't work on MyISAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table `module` you made the `subject_id` column nullable (i.e. it can take `NULL` values).  But, in the parent table `faculty`, `subject_id` is not nullable.  Make `subject_id` not nullable in the child table as well:

```
CREATE TABLE module (
    Subject_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    Subject VARCHAR(20), 
    module_1 BLOB, 
    module_2 BLOB, 
    module_3 BLOB, 
    module_4 BLOB, 
    module_5 BLOB, 
    FOREIGN KEY (Subject_id) REFERENCES faculty(Subject_id)
);
```

As a general rule, foreign and parent key types have to agree exactly.  This isn't always a requirement on MySQL, which can be lax, but you should still stick to this rule whenever possible.